# Higher order function - Python

Tags: python

I have an assignment to write a code in high order function (Function 1). However, I do not know why I should write it like that instead of normal one (Function 2). I would really appreciate if someone could show me when High order function is better.

```
# Function 1 (High order):
def high_function (L):
    def function (x):
        total = 0
        for i in range(len(L)):
            total = total + x **(len(L) - 1 - i) * L[i]
        return total
    return function

# Function 2 (Normal):
def high_function (L, x):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(L)):
        total = total + x **(len(L) - 1 - i) * L[i]
    return total
```

Comment: Because the first allows you to not have either `L` or `x` depending on where you are in the code.

Comment: Can you rephrase this as a question, preferably one that is not a matter of opinion? If you want a discussion of style or practice, there are sites like dreamincode.net which encourage those sorts of questions.

Comment: well... this is kind of higher order but not the most common kind ot higher order functions we would like to make sense of. this transformation is called curry isomorphism, which turns a multi parameter function into function returning function. higher order functions are useful when it accepts other functions, which means functions become one of the parameter. i agree with you that this type of code makes much less sense in the context of python.

Answer (score 2):

First, give your functions a better name, so the usage is more clearly:

```
def polynomial(factors):
    def eval(x):
        result = 0
        for factor in factors:
            result = x * result + factor
        return result
    return eval
```

So the function is used to define a polynomial, which can be used to evaluate for different `x`:

```
parabola = polynomial([1, 0, 0])
```

And to use it somewhere else:

```
value = parabola(0.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I lack formal knowledge of functional programming, but in essence, having higher order functions allows you to create functions as needed and pass them to other higher order functions.

Just like objects can take in other objects, languages that treat functions as first class citizens allow functions to be passed into other functions.

Consider this example,

```
def add(a):
    def func(b):
      return a + b

    return func
```

This `add` function can be used to create functions as needed

```
twoMore = add(2)
x = 10
xPlusTwo = twoMore(x)
```

Note that when you create a function within a function, the inner function is within a closure and has access to the scope of the outer function. In the case of the `add` function, the inner `func` has access to `a` when it returned by `add` and used in `twoMore`.

Just to conclude my point about passing functions around, consider this other example

```
def filter_list(valid, list):
    return [item for item in list
                if valid(item)]

def is_greater_than(value):
    def func(item):
        return item > value

    return func

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
gt5 = is_greater_than(5)
new_list = filter_list(gt5, my_list)
```